# Cannot read properties of this object values of parent component to child component function in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular14, angular-component-life-cycle

I'm calling a function declared in parent component in the child component in the form of callback.

Parent Component

`translation-editor.component.ts`

```
export class TranslationEditorComponent implements OnInit {
    textGuid: string = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['textGuid'];
    editDataset: any;
    currentTopBarConfig: any;
    summaryTopbarConfig = [
      {
        "label": "Save Text",
        "function": this.save,    //see save function below
      },
      { 
        "label": "Delete Text", 
        "function": this.delete, 
      }
    ];
  constructor(
    private translationService:TranslationService,
    public actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadDataToEdit();
  }
  loadDataToEdit(){
    this.translationService.getTextById(this.textGuid).subscribe(res => {
      this.editDataset = res;
    })
    this.currentTopBarConfig = this.summaryTopbarConfig;
  }
  save(){
    console.log("this.textGuid",this.textGuid);
    if(this.textGuid){
      this.translationService.updateText(this.textGuid, this.editDataset).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }
  delete(){
 console.log("delete code lies here");
  }
}
```

`translation-editor.component.html`

```
<topbar [config]="currentTopBarConfig"></topbar>

<form  [ngClass]="{'hidden':currentTab!=='summary'}" >
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Field</legend>
      <ul  *ngIf="editDataset">
        <ng-container  *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(editDataset)" >
          <li *ngIf="key === 'textGuid' || key === 'strongName' || key === 'container'">
            <label class="grid-input-group">
              <input type="text" value="{{editDataset[key]}}" readonly>
              <span class="label">{{key}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ng-container>

      </ul>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
```

I'm calling the save function in the below component as a callback to initiateFunction() function.

Child Component

`topbar.component.html`

```
<ul class="sidebar-items">
<ng-container *ngFor="let btn of config">
  <li>
    <button 
      (click)="initiateFunction(btn.function)"
      <span class="label" >{{btn.label}}</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ng-container>
</ul>
```

`topbar.component.ts`

```
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() config: any[] | undefined;
    constructor(private location: Location) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    initiateFunction(fnct:any){
      fnct();
    }
  }
```

Here when function is executed I'm getting an error:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textGuid')**

Where I'm not able access the this.textGuid.

Please give me suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: According to your code `TranslationEditorComponent` is the parent component and using `TopbarComponent` in HTML template. I can't see `currentTopBarConfig` anywhere inside `TranslationEditorComponent`. Where does `currentTopBarConfig` variable is declared and initialized?

Comment: @FadiHania `currentTopBarConfig` is assigned to  `summaryTopbarConfig`

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that

Comment: Any suggestion on how to solve this @FadiHania

Comment: Checking that now, I'll update shortly

Comment: okay @FadiHania

Comment: Why do you have `summaryTopbarConfig` as an array? It has only a single object

Comment: Actually delete option is also there to simplify code i did like that `      {
        "label":    "Delete Text",
        "function": this.delete,
      }, ` @FadiHania

Comment: Both should be calling the same `save()` function?

Comment: No ` { "label": "Delete Text", "function": this.delete, }, `    `delete()` function is also there as per the object @FadiHania

Comment: I've posted an answer, let me know if that works with you

Comment: Can you check my answer and accept if it works? Or give feedback if have any errors, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is caused because the `save()` function isn't bound to the correct object, so instead you can use Angular component interaction features. You can use `@Output` decorator and emit an event that will be handled by parent component.

First, update your `TopbarComponent` to add that event:

`topbar.component.ts`

```js
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: any[] | undefined;
  @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  
  constructor(private location: Location) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  onSave() {
    this.save.emit();
    //fnct();
  }
}
```

`topbar.component.html` there was a typo on in button start tag >

```html
<ul class="sidebar-items">
<ng-container *ngFor="let btn of config">
  <li>
    <button 
      (click)="onSave()">
      <span class="label" >{{btn.label}}</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ng-container>
</ul>
```

Next, update the `TranslationEditorComponent` component to bind to that event:
`translation-editor.component.html`

```html
<topbar [config]="currentTopBarConfig" (save)="save()"></topbar>
```

You can do the same for other types of events like delete or update. Refer to Angular docs for more details about components interaction and sharing data https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 1):

Your **this** context has been changed when you call `fnct();`. In order to pass the **this** context to the function you can use javascript *bind* method.
So you just need to change the config property:

```
summaryTopbarConfig = [
      {
        "label": "Save Text",
        "function": this.save.bind(this),    //bind current context
      }
    ];
```

Read more about *bind*: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_bind.asp

Comment: But In my opinion, it will be better to use `EventEmitter` if you want to call a method from child component that is defined in parent